# Get distance filtered using google API

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, filter, gps, distance

I'm working on an Android Studio project using Firebase as my database. How am I going to filter the places using google GPS to obtain the nearest places from the user? For example, when the user clicks on the option "within 2km", the system will sort out the places within 2km from the users' current place. Thanks if anyone can provide me a guideline on this.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete
In optional parameters you can use radius or strictbounds if you are using Place Autocomplete.